# How can I link ROOT libraries in Makefile for VSCode in Windows 11?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, makefile, vscode-snippets, root-framework

I am a newbie when it comes to VSCode and especially working with ROOT. I have a C++ project with a Makefile that uses ROOT libraries. The Makefile was created for Linux and I tried to adapt it for my Windows, but it seems not to work.

This is the Makefile:

```
$(info $(SHELL))
OBJECTS = Nucleus.o Mass.o Chart.o Yrast.o TlArray.o  LevelDensity.o Angle.o Nuclide.o LightP.o Evap.o AngleDist.o Random.o TlBarDist.o Scission.o  Weight.o   SigCharged.o SigBarDist.o Fus.o Run.o

ROOT_LIB_DIR = "C:\root_v6.28.06\lib"
export LIBPATH := $(ROOT_LIB_DIR)
ALLOBJECTS := $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(wildcard *.cpp))
FOBJECTS:=$(patsubst %.f,%.o,$(wildcard *.f))
LIBS = -L$(LIBPATH) -lCore -lImt -lRIO -lNet -lHist -lGraf -lGraf3d -lGpad -lROOTVecOps -lTree -lTreePlayer -lRint -lPostscript -lMatrix -lPhysics -lMathCore -lThread -lGui
CFLAGS=  -c -g -Wall  -I"C:\root_v6.28.06\include" $(LIBS)
COMPILER= g++

testDecay:  testDecay.o $(OBJECTS)
    $(COMPILER) -o testDecay testDecay.o $(OBJECTS)  

main: main.o $(OBJECTS)
    $(COMPILER) -o main main.o $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS)

testGemini:: testGemini.o gemini.o $(OBJECTS)
    f77 -o testGemini testGemini.o gemini.o $(OBJECTS) -lstdc++

gemini.a: $(OBJECTS)
    ar rcs gemini.a $(OBJECTS)
    ranlib gemini.a

$(ALLOBJECTS): %.o : %.cpp
    $(COMPILER) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(FOBJECTS): %.o : %.f
    f77 $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@


clean:
    del *.o
```

From the error that I receive, I assume that the order of the libraries is incorrect, because whenever I try to use `make main`, I get this error:

```
g++ -o main main.o Nucleus.o Mass.o Chart.o Yrast.o TlArray.o  LevelDensity.o Angle.o Nuclide.o LightP.o Evap.o AngleDist.o Random.o TlBarDist.o Scission.o  Weight.o   SigCharged.o SigBarDist.o Fus.o Run.o -L"C:\root_v6.28.06\lib" -lCore -lImt -lRIO -lNet -lHist -lGraf -lGraf3d -lGpad -lROOTVecOps -lTree -lTreePlayer -lRint -lPostscript -lMatrix -lPhysics -lMathCore -lThread -lGui
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: main.o: in function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
C:/root_v6.28.06/include/TVersionCheck.h:31:(.text+0x8c7): undefined reference to `TVersionCheck::TVersionCheck(int)'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Run.o: in function `CRun::CRun(int, int, float, float, float, int, float, int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, float, float, float)':
C:/Users/asaca/Master/AN1S1/SC/Proiect/Code3/Run.cpp:57:(.text+0x36a): undefined reference to `TFile::TFile(char const*, char const*, char const*, int)'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/asaca/Master/AN1S1/SC/Proiect/Code3/Run.cpp:58:(.text+0x3c5): undefined reference to `TTree::TTree(char const*, char const*, int, TDirectory*)'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/asaca/Master/AN1S1/SC/Proiect/Code3/Run.cpp:86:(.text+0x4c7): undefined reference to `Form(char const*, ...)'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/asaca/Master/AN1S1/SC/Proiect/Code3/Run.cpp:87:(.text+0x519): undefined reference to `Form(char const*, ...)'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/asaca/Master/AN1S1/SC/Proiect/Code3/Run.cpp:93:(.text+0x66e): undefined reference to `Form(char const*, ...)'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/asaca/Master/AN1S1/SC/Proiect/Code3/Run.cpp:95:(.text+0x6c3): undefined reference to `Form(char const*, ...)'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/asaca/Master/AN1S1/SC/Proiect/Code3/Run.cpp:96:(.text+0x718): undefined reference to `Form(char const*, ...)'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Run.o:C:/Users/asaca/Master/AN1S1/SC/Proiect/Code3/Run.cpp:97: more undefined references to `Form(char const*, ...)' follow
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Run.o: in function `CRun::CRun(int, int, float, float, float, int, float, int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, float, float, float)':
C:/Users/asaca/Master/AN1S1/SC/Proiect/Code3/Run.cpp:57:(.text+0x108a): undefined reference to `TObject::operator delete(void*)'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/asaca/Master/AN1S1/SC/Proiect/Code3/Run.cpp:58:(.text+0x109f): undefined reference to `TObject::operator delete(void*)'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Run.o: in function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
C:/root_v6.28.06/include/TVersionCheck.h:31:(.text+0x10fd): undefined reference to `TVersionCheck::TVersionCheck(int)'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Run.o: in function `TObject::operator new(unsigned long long)':
C:/root_v6.28.06/include/TObject.h:181:(.text$_ZN7TObjectnwEy[_ZN7TObjectnwEy]+0x14): undefined reference to `TStorage::ObjectAlloc(unsigned long long)'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Run.o: in function `ROOT::Internal::TDirectoryAtomicAdapter::TDirectoryAtomicAdapter()':
C:/root_v6.28.06/include/TDirectory.h:345:(.text$_ZN4ROOT8Internal23TDirectoryAtomicAdapterC1Ev[_ZN4ROOT8Internal23TDirectoryAtomicAdapterC1Ev]+0xd): undefined reference to `TDirectory::GetSharedLocalCurrentDirectory()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:16: main] Error 1
```

I already checked the compiler and the make command and they work properly.
`make clean` works correctly for my project and the `make main` command also begins correctly, it just crashes when it comes to libraries. I can't find the correct order of the libraries, if that is the issue.

Can you help me?

EDIT: - The complete list of libraries

```
-cppyy3_8.lib
-cppyy_backend3_8.lib
-libASImage.lib
-libASImageGui.lib
-libCling.lib
-libcomplexDict.lib
-libCore.lib
-libdequeDict.lib
-libEG.lib
-libEve.lib
-libFFTW.lib
-libFitPanel.lib
-libFITSIO.lib
-libFoam.lib
-libforward_listDict.lib
-libFTGL.lib
-libFumili.lib
-libGdml.lib
-libGed.lib
-libGenetic.lib
-libGenVector.lib
-libGeom.lib
-libGeomBuilder.lib
-libGeomPainter.lib
-libGLEW.lib
-libGpad.lib
-libGraf.lib
-libGraf3d.lib
-libGui.lib
-libGuiBld.lib
-libGuiHtml.lib
-libGviz3d.lib
-libHist.lib
-libHistFactory.lib
-libHistPainter.lib
-libHtml.lib
-libImt.lib
-liblistDict.lib
-libmap2Dict.lib
-libmapDict.lib
-libMathCore.lib
-libMatrix.lib
-libMinuit.lib
-libMinuit2.lib
-libMLP.lib
-libmultimap2Dict.lib
-libmultimapDict.lib
-libmultisetDict.lib
-libNet.lib
-libPhysics.lib
-libPostscript.lib
-libProof.lib
-libProofDraw.lib
-libProofPlayer.lib
-libPyMVA.lib
-libQuadp.lib
-libRCsg.lib
-libRecorder.lib
-libRGL.lib
-libRHTTP.lib
-libRHTTPSniff.lib
-libRint.lib
-libRIO.lib
-libRooBatchCompute.lib
-libRooBatchCompute_GENERIC.lib
-libRooFit.lib
-libRooFitCommon.lib
-libRooFitCore.lib
-libRooFitHS3.lib
-libRooFitJSONInterface.lib
-libRooFitRDataFrameHelpers.lib
-libRooStats.lib
-libRootAuth.lib
-libROOTBranchBrowseProvider.lib
-libROOTBrowsable.lib
-libROOTBrowserGeomWidget.lib
-libROOTBrowserRCanvasWidget.lib
-libROOTBrowserTCanvasWidget.lib
-libROOTBrowserTreeWidget.lib
-libROOTBrowserv7.lib
-libROOTBrowserWidgets.lib
-libROOTCanvasPainter.lib
-libROOTDataFrame.lib
-libROOTEve.lib
-libROOTFitPanelv7.lib
-libROOTGeomViewer.lib
-libROOTGpadv7.lib
-libROOTGraphicsPrimitives.lib
-libROOTHist.lib
-libROOTHistDraw.lib
-libROOTHistDrawProvider.lib
-libROOTLeafDraw6Provider.lib
-libROOTLeafDraw7Provider.lib
-libROOTNTuple.lib
-libROOTNTupleBrowseProvider.lib
-libROOTNTupleDraw6Provider.lib
-libROOTNTupleDraw7Provider.lib
-libROOTNTupleUtil.lib
-libROOTObjectDraw6Provider.lib
-libROOTObjectDraw7Provider.lib
-libROOTTMVASofie.lib
-libROOTTPython.lib
-libROOTTreeViewer.lib
-libROOTVecOps.lib
-libROOTWebDisplay.lib
-libSessionViewer.lib
-libsetDict.lib
-libSmatrix.lib
-libSpectrum.lib
-libSpectrumPainter.lib
-libSPlot.lib
-libSQLIO.lib
-libThread.lib
-libTMVA.lib
-libTMVAGui.lib
-libTree.lib
-libTreePlayer.lib
-libTreeViewer.lib
-libunordered_mapDict.lib
-libunordered_multimapDict.lib
-libunordered_multisetDict.lib
-libunordered_setDict.lib
-libUnuran.lib
-libvectorDict.lib
-libWebGui6.lib
-libWin32gdk.lib
-libXMLIO.lib
-tbb.lib
-tbbmalloc.lib
-tbbmalloc_proxy.lib
```

Comment: There are many unresolveds in Run.cpp (Run.o). It seems that the order of libraries is not the reason... What library exports TFile for example?

Comment: @SergeyVlasov I am not sure how to check. TFile.h is in the include directory of the ROOT that is included in `-I"C:\root_v6.28.06\include"` part of CFLAGS. But yes, most of the problems seem to come from Run.cpp. Could it be an include issue? This is how it is defined the include part for Run.cpp: #include "CRun.h"
#include <TTree.h>
#include <TMath.h>
#include <TTreeIndex.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <istream>

Comment: This error tells us that this is not an include issue. Include issues are compiler issues. You have the linker issue: C:/Users/asaca/Master/AN1S1/SC/Proiect/Code3/Run.cpp:57:(.text+0x36a): undefined reference to `TFile::TFile(char const*, char const*, char const*, int)'  ==== This means that compiler found TFile::TFile() declaration but linker couldn't find it's definition. ==== Please give the full list of libraries in C:\root_v6.28.06\lib. Have you used all of them in Makefile (LIBS =) ?

Comment: @SergeyVlasov I added the complete list of libraries in the /lib directory. I have not used all of them on the LIBS variable, only the recommended ones. I am not sure which one refers the file TFile.h

Comment: As a beginner, stay away from VSCode. It is *not* beginner friendly.